# Put string in componentname

Tags: android

I want to disable default android launcher. As I understand it can be done by using this `setComponentEnabledSetting` and this `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED`.But I don't understand how to put "com.android.launcher" in `ComponentName`.Can somebody help me?

Comment: "As I understand it can be done by using this setComponentEnabledSetting and this COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED" -- that is for disabling your own components. You cannot disable components of other apps this way, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare So,I can't disable default android launcher using all these?

Comment: Correct. Besides, that launcher is not available on most devices. Most device manufacturers use their own launcher.

Comment: @commonsware But if it's not possible to disable default android launcher then how do manufacturers did this?

Comment: They build their own devices. They control a lot of what is installed on those devices, just as PC manufacturers control a lot of what is installed on PCs that they sell. You are welcome to build your own Android custom ROM, and in that ROM *you* can decide what the launcher is. However, the only people that will affect are those who replace their entire Android with your custom ROM.

Comment: @commonsware Thanks a lot!!! You've just saved a lot of my time!